# Can't get a multi-app webpack configuration to work with react-hot-loader

Tags: webpack, react-hot-loader, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware

I have a basic setup with two apps each in a separate directory, I'm using a custom server to compile them using `webpack-dev-middleware`/`webpack-hot-middleware`. Things are working fine except that I can't get HMR to work for the second app (I'm using `react-hot-loader`).

Here's a minimal repo illustrating the problem: https://github.com/AmrN/multi-react-app-hmr

My main code files:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (appName) {
  return {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      path.join(__dirname, appName, 'index'),
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', appName),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/'+appName+'/'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(__dirname, appName, 'index.html'),
      }),
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }]
    },
  };
};
```

**server.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var express = require('express');
var config1 = require('./webpack.config')('app1');
var config2 = require('./webpack.config')('app2');

var app = express();

[config1, config2].forEach((config) => {
  var compiler = webpack(config);
  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
});

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

**(app1|app2)/index.js**

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');
const render = Component =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    rootEl
  );

render(App);
if (module.hot) module.hot.accept('./App', () => render(App));
```

Now if I run the server, my files are compiled correctly, and I can visit `http://localhost:3000/app1/index.html` successfully, and HMR is working properly here. However, if I visit the second app `http://localhost:3000/app2/index.html` it opens but HMR is not working and looking at the console it gives me the following error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/app2/640a44b6b47b67436af2.hot-update.json
>   404 (Not Found)
>
> [HMR] Cannot find update (Full reload needed)
>
> [HMR] (Probably because of restarting the server)

Another thing I've noticed is that changing the order in which I apply my apps webpack configs in server.js from:

`[config1, config2].forEach((config) => {...})`

to:

`[config2, config1].forEach((config) => {...})`

switches the problem to app1, now HMR works for app2 but not app1.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that both apps used the same path for hot reloading (I think it's `/__webpack_hmr` by default).
So I had to use a different one for each:

in **webpack.config.js** I did:

```
entry: [
  // ...
  'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr_'+appName,
  // ...
]
```

and in **server.js**:

```
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
  path: '/__webpack_hmr_'+appName
}));
```

Now it's working properly.